# My latex table does not work as it should

Tags: errors

I am trying to solve this issue but I keep getting an error that I cannot get rid of. However the code works fine and compiles every time with the changes.

The error:

```
Missing $ inserted.
                $
l.6  \# & \Leftarrow
                     & cell3 & Cel \\
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.

! Extra }, or forgotten $.
 \unskip \hfil }
                          \hskip \tabcolsep \hskip -.5\arrayrulewidth \vrule...
l.6  \# & \Leftarrow &
                       cell3 & Cel \\
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
```

and

```
Missing $ inserted.
                $
l.6  \# & \Leftarrow &
                       cell3 & Cel \\
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think
you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.

! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.6  \# & \Leftarrow &
                       cell3 & Cel \\
I've inserted something that you may have forgotten.
(See the <inserted text> above.)
With luck, this will get me unwedged. But if you
really didn't forget anything, try typing `2' now; then
my insertion and my current dilemma will both disappear.
```

My code is as follows:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c| } 
 \hline
 \# & \Leftarrow & cell3 & Cel \\ 
 cell2 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 
 cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: please post a fully compilable MWE. many thanks. but my guess is it should be `$\leftarrow$`

Comment: You need `$\Leftarrow$`...

Comment: Thanks, I love you soo much, I cant believe that it was something that simple. I spent 3h to fix that. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You need to insert math-related content using math-mode. That is, use

```
$\Leftarrow$
```